# Reversing array code explanation in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Would someone explain what each line does in the following code? I am basically confused with -1 and -i.

Also is there anyway we could reverse an array without TEMP value?

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length / 2; i++) { // why divide by 2
     int temp = numbers[i];
     numbers[i] = numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i];// what this does?
     numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i] = temp;`i];
     numbers[numbers.length - 1 - i] = temp;
```

Comment: Looks like you received two helpful responses below. Were they any good? Did they help you understand the code? If so, consider replying with further questions, upvoting or accepting. These actions are not mandatory, but we'd have no community here if no-one ever interacted with people who aided them.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, this loop is swapping the position of the values in the array.

For example, take this array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

The loop starts by setting the element at `i` to the variable `temp`.
Then, the number at the end of the array **minus** how many iterations/positions (`i`) we have moved forward, is set to the current position of the array (`i`) thus replacing `1`. In other words, it selects the furthest element from itself that hasn't been swapped. Right after that, `temp` is set to the position of the old position of `4`.

The first iteration causes the array to look like `[4, 2, 3, 1]`

The second iteration causes the array to look like `[4, 3, 2, 1]`

The array is now reversed. But notice that we only iterated half the length of the array. There is no need to keep iterating and if we were to go any further, we would get an array out of bounds error.

(The reason for the `-1` is because the `.length` returns the number of elements in the array counting up from **1**)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array has a length of `10`, the first iteration would do this

`i = 0`

```
int temp = numbers[0];
numbers[0] = numbers[10 - 1 - 0]; // first value becomes the last value in the array
numbers[10 - 1 - 0]  = temp; // last value becomes the previously first value in the array
```

`2` values change in one step, so you need `(length / 2)` steps to get the job done.

If you want to swap two integers without using an additional variable, you can use the `xor` bitwise operator (`^`)

An example:

```
int x = -10;
int y = 125;
x ^= y;
y ^= x;
x ^= y;
```

More details about the theory behind it [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)